# how to change y-axis position of cursor in fabric js textbox

Tags: fabricjs

how to set pointer position of cursor as per requirement?
In fabric text box the x-axis position can be changed but how to override the y-axis value as per requirement?

Comment: Please provide more details about your issue.

Comment: I want to make the cursor size larger,please find the demo..[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ayan27/pofpnuq3/12/)

Comment: the cursor position can be moved according to  x-axis but want to change  its Y-axis position or want to be down or up from its current position.

Comment: Are you talking about padding ?

Comment: (https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/1948) please go through this link,I am facing the same problem.

Comment: in this link you can see that the cursor goes up from the text,how can it be adjusted?

Comment: Ok got it, Actually the cursor position is according to the hiddenTextArea of the text box, It creates the hiddenTextArea every time you enter editing. Can you plz tell me in which case you are getting this issue ?, Are you changing the width/height of canvas ?

Comment: actually I am loading custom font,when I am editing I am facing this problem, hiddenTextArea of text box can be adjustable? I am sharing the screen shot also where the lower portion of 'j' also hiding at the time of grouping.please help me if the hidden TextArea  can be adjustable. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QozzyQvf1v6Meg5MAoB-RwxZhlTlHLV/view)

Comment: Are you sure that the fonts you are using are already loaded ? When you use fonts in fabricjs they should be already loaded.

Comment: yes, I am loading font-family inside the @font-face and at the time of creating new textbox defining the font family

Comment: what do you mean by already loaded? can you please explain by demo code?

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://fabricjs.com/loadfonts)

Comment: @Durga in this demo please change the font to 'Pacifico' and write small 'j',the lower portion of 'j' is going out of the text box area,how to fix it?